# Clickhouse - Matrix entrywise addition: how to sum 2 dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, clickhouse

What is the proper and fastest way to calculate entrywise sum of matrices in table using Clickhouse database?

I have found such solution. But it seems to me it's not optimal enough.
And one more, I need to specify sumForEach() for each element of the one dimension.

```
select array(sumForEach(matrix[1]), sumForEach(matrix[2])) from (
 select 1 as id, [[1,3], [2,4]] as matrix
 union all
 select 2 as id, [[2,4], [3,5]] as matrix
 union all
 select 3 as id, [[1,2], [1,0]] as matrix
)
```

as a result, I want to see one row with the resulting matrix

```
┌─m─────────────┐
│[[4,9],[6,9]]  │
└───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aggregate function combinators](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/) can be applied many times, that help to simplify query:

```sql
SELECT sumForEachForEach(matrix)
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS id, 
        [[1, 3], [2, 4]] AS matrix
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        2 AS id, 
        [[2, 4], [3, 5]] AS matrix
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        3 AS id, 
        [[1, 2], [1, 0]] AS matrix
)
/*
┌─sumForEachForEach(matrix)─┐
│ [[4,9],[6,9]]             │
└───────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! It turned out so simple and elegant ... but from the docks it was difficult to understand about such combination